# Arduino -> Conflito função/variável/biblioteca

Tags: c, arduino

Estou a fazer um programa em Arduino. Estou a utilizar o adaptador OBDII (UART) da Freematics. Eles desenvolveram uma biblioteca específica. Há um problema: a tentar ler uma PID, que me devolve 2 bytes com um valor entre 0 e 65535. Supostamente devia guardar esse valor numa variável unsigned int (0 a 65535). Mas a função que me faz devolver esse valor só aceita variáveis do tipo int(-32768 a 32767). Qual a solução? Retificar a biblioteca toda? De alguma forma ir buscar o valor sem usar a função?

**Função** ->  obd.readPID("pid", "variavel")  //  `obd.readPID(PID_RUNTIME, tempo_motor);`

> COBD::readPID(byte pid, int& result)

**Biblioteca** -> https://github.com/stanleyhuangyc/ArduinoOBD/tree/master/libraries/OBD2UART

Ao correr o programa, com o adaptador ligado ao carro, quando chega a essa linha de código o programa simplesmente pára (fica mto tempo a tentar ler o valor da PID) e acaba por passar para a próxima linha de código. Se usar uma variável que não a int aparece o seguinte erro:

```
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'COBD::readPID(int, unsigned int&)
```

Comment: Bom, neste caso está dizendo que não existe esta função para chamar... Você importou todas as libs corretas ?

Comment: Eu penso que sim. No site da Freematics (desenvolvedores do adaptador) e no GitHub foi apenas o que encontrei.